# Batch run time against run time of code without batch

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How accurate are the start-/stop-timestamps in batch-history?

I've noticed, that a batch runtime is declared with one minute in the history. The code executed by the batch includes a find-method and only if this returns false, further code is executed. The find-method itself runs nearly instantly.

I've added timestamps in code via info-logs and can see those in the history of the batch. one timestamp is at the very first line and another one at the very last line of code. the delta is 0.

So I'm asking, from what this time-delta (stop-start of history against timestamps in code) comes from?!
Is there any "overhead" or sth. which takes an amount of time everytime a batch is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps in `BatchJobHistory` (Batch job history) are off by up to a minute.
The timestamps in `BatchHistory` (Show tasks) are pretty accurate (one second resolution).

The timestamps in `BatchJobHistory` represents when the batch was started and observed finished by the batch system. Due to implementation details this may differ by 60 seconds from the real execution times recorded in `BatchHistory`.

This is yet another reason why it is difficult to monitor the AX batch system.